# How to fix error "long* is incompatible with U32**"?

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

I try to call a function with the following signature:

```
I32 contour8(image *a, I32 x0, I32 y0, I32 dir, I32 thr, U32 lng, U32 **dst);
```

Using this code:

```
int posx = 100, posy = 100, dx = 300, dy = 300;
long length = 5000;
int threshold = 125;
int lx, x0 = 0, y0 = 0;
int res1 = 0, res2 = 0, *rlc, *input, i;
long dest1, dest2, desttemp, addr;
char c;
image Area;

desttemp = dest1;
res1 = contour8(&Area, x0, y0, ~2, threshold, length, &desttemp);
```

But when compiling I get the following error:

```
error argument of type "long *" is incompatible with parameter of type "U32 **"
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Why have 4 people voted to close this? The question is not off-topic, as the poster is not asking for code. If you just think that a question is bad, the right thing to do is to down vote, not close vote. Don't abuse your reputation privileges.

Comment: I agree. The question is bad, and should be reworded. And perhaps closed for that reason, but it isnt off topic,

Answer (score 7):

Your variable `desttemp` is of type `long`. `&desttemp` results in `long*` which you try to pass to `contour8` as parameter `dst` which is of type `U32**`.

`long*` is not implicitly convertible to `U32**` which results in your error.

You should either make `desttemp` a `U32*` (recommended), or cast `&desttemp` to `U32**` (not recommended; this would introduce other issues as long as you don't know what you are doing). Since we do not know what your function does / expects you ultimately need to decide yourself which one suits best in your case.

Answer (score -4):

In 32 bit system, size of long variable is 64 bit. So it you are passing a 64 bit value in 32 variable getting error is probable. 
Moreover a simple advise always initialize all the variables  during declaration you are not initializing some variables and pointers, being a programmer it is considered to be as bad practice. cheers.. :)

Comment: `sizeof(long) == 8` is not true for LLP64 platforms (e.g. Windows).

Comment: The problem is passing a pointer to a number rather than a pointer to some buffer area.

Comment: Furthermore, not initializing variables explicitly isn't necessarily bad practice, if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Downvote because this doesnt actually address the problem of pointer-to-pointer vs pointer.